# How to create a SQL database and use it in same script?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is my script:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydbname;
USE mydbname;
```

If I run 1st line, then 2nd line, it works OK.

If I run both together then I get this error:

> Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> Database 'mydbname' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

What is the correct way to write this script?

Answer (score 2):

Use `GO` inbetween:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydbname;
GO
USE mydbname;
```